# Collect number (of citations) from internet

Tags: lyx

I would like to insert a "dynamic" number in my TeX (actually LyX) file. In particular, I am working on a literature review and would like to add the number of google citations. For example:

Grossman and Stiglitz (1980, XX)

Where XX corresponds to the number of results (# of citations, now 6370) in the google scholar search:
https://scholar.google.de/scholar?num=100&espv=2&um=1&ie=UTF-8&lr&cites=16114158033156884318

I think that the number of citations helps me and my students to get a better sense of the importance of certain academic papers in the literature. To keep the file up-to date, the above requested dynamic link would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Sweave, with an R snippet that access the web info. I'm assuming you will use links that return numbers, not search results (as the provided link does). I could post the snippet if you posted a link that provides a number.

Comment: That would be great! I do not know, however, how to get such a link. The only thing i see is "cited by XX". Examples are shown in the link I put in the opening post. Sorry that I can be not more specific (